# Redis replication vs Redis Sentinel in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-sentinel

Redis provides a basic [replication mechanism](https://redis.io/docs/management/replication/) and more advanced [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/docs/management/sentinel/). As far as I understand the main advantage of the Sentinel is high availability. If the master node fails, the sentinel will automatically detect it and promote a slave node to the master. But if we deploy Redis into k8s we get the same feature for default Redis replication. K8s will check the health of the master node for us and in case of a failure, will restart it. So, what is the purpose of using Redis Sentinel with k8s?

I have an assumptiom that with Redis Sentineil the new master gets up immidiatelly and we have zero downtime (not sure if it works that way) but k8s pod restart takes some time and the redis would be unavailable for that period.

I would appriciate it if someone could answer my question and explain the difference.